# Ajax Calls in IE9 random failure

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, internet-explorer-9

I've written an internet application that synchronizes every action by the user with the server. Therefore I have a lot of Ajax requests going (not at the same time though).

The application works great in Firefox and Chrome, but IE9 gives me a headache. I have totally random failures in IE9 with these post requests. Therefore, the problem is not reproducible by a clear action, however, it frequently occurs. If for example I perform exactly the same action ten times in a row, it can either succeed every time, or it can fail during one of these requests. I have profiled the network with IE Developer tools and it results in the following: http://screencast.com/t/VLcK5OKWQl

As you can see, the post request remains pending. In the detailed description of this call all info is blank, not even a request header.

I am totally lost with this problem. If anyone has any idea what this could be, please share with me, I will try anything!

By the way, I'm using jQuery (v1.7.1) $.post calls if this makes any difference. I've also included the following headers in the responding file:

```
header( 'Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate' );
header( 'Pragma: no-cache' );
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: have you tried using the standard $.ajax with the setting 'cache' to false?

Comment: Do you know if the request reach the server or its some cache problem? Could you monitor that?

Comment: @trembon: Doesn't jQuery automatically add cache=false to post requests? Anyway, I will try

Comment: @Simon: I'm running CentOS on a VPS. Any idea where I can find such logs? (I am not really into the server side)

Comment: @Simon: Or maybe with DirectAdmin?

Comment: @Bjorn: if you look on the documentation page of .post() cache is not included in the shorthand code, so i guess not

Comment: @trembon: I've tried your suggestion, but unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem. Thanks for the suggestion anyway!

Comment: can also use fiddler or similar utility to analyze the requests from local machine

Comment: I have checked the server logs, the request never reached the server. This really narrows the problem down to the browser, IE9 specific. Still left in great despair!

Comment: Is it possible that this has something to do with the keepalive settings? I've read that IE9 handles this differently, so maybe this could be the cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following headers solved the problem for me:

```
ob_end_clean();
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP 1.1.
header('Pragma: no-cache'); // HTTP 1.0.
header('Expires: 0'); // Proxies.
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had the exact same problem and was able to solve it by not sending null as data on the request (just sending an integer instead etc.).

I also tried running the same request multiple times to debug what went wrong, and before changing the argument to "not null" I got random responses (either success, a null value or an error (status code 12031).
After making the "not null argument" change, I've been able to run  the same request 1000+ times without any failure.

That said, I'm not able to reproduce this anywhere else... so, it still doesn't make any sense :P